# Tips for golfing in Seriously

Tags: code-golf, tips

I am looking for tips to code in this golfing language [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), and was wondering what some of the ways for golfing this language is. "Remove comments" is not a tip. [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/releases/tag/v2.0) is also included

Comment: Does this also cover [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/releases/tag/v2.0)? Seriously is the version 1, Actually is version 2